# Zero sets boolean algebra

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a distributive lattice and SpecA the set of prime ideals of A. The opens of SpecA are of the form $\{P|I\not\subseteq P\}$ for I an ideal of A.

We know that SpecA is Hausdorff iff A is a Boolean algebra.

The zero sets $Z(X)$ of a topological space $X$ form a distributive lattice and $SpecZ(X)$ is Hausdorff.

But $Z(X)$ is not a Boolean algebra in general. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is your source for Spec $Z(X)$ being Hausdorff?

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong. I found a proof that the subspace of maximal ideals of Z(X) is Hausdorff. Maximal ideals and prime ideals coincide when Z(X) = P(X), but not in general.